# Running command-line application from PHP as specific user

Tags: php, exec

I am running Apache on my localhost. From a PHP script run as www-user I would like to control Rhythmbox playback on my machine. So far I have a simple command in my PHP script:

`exec('rhythmbox-client --pause');`

This works great when I run it from the command-line as me, but if it runs as www-user I guess `rhythmbox-client` doesn't know/can't access my instance of Rhythmbox.

Is there an easy way for that PHP script to run as my user rather than www-user, or to tell `rhythmbox-client` which instance to control?

The overall application is that when my phone goes off-hook it calls my PHP script which pauses music, and resumes playback when the phone is on-hook. I love VoIP phones!

**Solution:**
Thanks to Carpetsmoker and Tarek I used `sudo` as the answer but there was a couple of problems. To overcome them I did the following:

Created a bash script to call `rhythmbox-client`. This bash script was executed using `sudo` in PHP as described in the answer below. Unfortunately `rhythmbox-client` didn't know what environment to control, so the bash script looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
DBUS_ADDRESS=`grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/*/environ 2> /dev/null| sed 's/DBUS/\nDBUS/g' | tail -n 1`
if [ "x$DBUS_ADDRESS" != "x" ]; then
        export $DBUS_ADDRESS
        /usr/bin/rhythmbox-client --pause
fi
```

Now that bash script can be executed by PHP and wwwuser, and my phone can pause/play my music!

Comment: what about to try to run rhythmbox-client not-as-root?

Comment: Are you planning on only running your server locally? (aka never putting it online)

Comment: @afuzzyllama Yes it's just locally

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One solution is using `sudo(8)`:

```
exec('sudo -u myuser ls /');
```

You will, obviously, need to setup `sudo(8)` to allow the user running your webserver to invoke it. Editing the sudoers file with `visudo(8)`, you can use something like:

```
wwwuser ALL=/usr/bin/rhythmbox-client
```

To prevent Apache from being able to run other commands and *only* the rythymbox command.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I edited `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo`, but when I exec `sudo -u myuser rhythmbox-client --pause` I am prompted for the wwwuser password. Is there any way to avoid password authentication for this instance?

Comment: change it to `wwwuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rhythmbox-client`

Comment: Thanks I changed it to `wwwuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rhythmbox-client`. It works great if I run it from the command-line as wwwuser, but my PHP script won't run it when called through Apache :(

Comment: Thanks both for your help, I posted final solution in the answer. It wasn't just user permissions after all!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, What about Windows Server?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the solution came this way:

1. Added this lines to sudoers file:

   myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/prlctl
   _www ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/prlctl     # IMPORTANT!!!
2. The EXEC() command in PHP was changed to:

   exec("sudo -u myuser prlctl list -a", $out, $r);

Answer (score -3):

If a process can be run by any user it can be run by PHP. Example is `fortune` command

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18816 Oct  1  2009 /usr/games/fortune
```

Look at the `x` permission for every user. But this some times doesn't at all work and you may have to let the user, `www-data` or `apache` etc, run the program. You can `sudo www-data` and try to run the command. If it works then Apache/PHP should be able to run it.