# Set volume using php exec and amixer

Tags: php, apache, exec, alsa, amixer

I wrote a little php script to control the volume of my local machine with alsa:

```
<?php
# for simplicity and testing it really just executes the command:
echo exec('amixer set Master 5%+') . " \n";
```

Now when I run this script on command line it works fine:

```
$ php volume.php 
Front Right: Playback 39226 [60%] [on] 
$ php volume.php 
Front Right: Playback 42503 [65%] [on] 
$ php volume.php 
Front Right: Playback 45780 [70%] [on]
```

I have music playing and I hear it getting louder.

But when I try to run the script via apache from the browser calling `http://localhost/volume.php` it doesn't work.

```
# http://localhost/volume.php
Front Right: Playback 55709 [10%] [on]
# F5
Front Right: Playback 55709 [15%] [on]
# F5
Front Right: Playback 55709 [20%] [on]
```

Now I hear no change in volume and the percentages seem to be unrelated to the current state. It says 10% - 15% - 20% when it really is still at 70%.

My apache is running as my user so `exec('whoami')` gives me the username I am logged in with on my shell where everything works fine.

```
# httpd.conf
User mkt
Group mkt
```

I'm on Fedora 22.

Probably it's due to the apache2 process environment.
Any ideas how to fix this?

**UPDATE**:

This is the output of aplay -L:

```
[mkt@localhost ~]$ aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
default
    Default ALSA Output (currently PulseAudio Sound Server)
sysdefault:CARD=Intel
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
```

On command line only default and pulse are working:

```
amixer -D pulse set Master 5%+
amixer -D default set Master 5%+
```

With PHP even those two don't work.
Anyway... my sound comes from my monitors speakers which is plugged in via hdmi. So I guess the last 4 devices are my candidates. But non of them work.

```
$ amixer -D hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0 set Master 5%+
$ amixer -D hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1 set Master 5%+
$ amixer -D hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2 set Master 5%+
$ amixer -D hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3 set Master 5%+
```

In all four cases it says:
(with DEV=[0-3] of course)

```
ALSA lib control.c:954:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
amixer: Mixer attach hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3 error: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE**

Output of aplay -l:

```
$ aplay -l

**** List of Hardware-Devices (PLAYBACK) ****
Card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], Device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]
  Sub-Devices: 1/1
  Sub-Device #0: subdevice #0
Card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], Device 1: ALC888 Digital [ALC888 Digital]
  Sub-Devices: 1/1
  Sub-Device #0: subdevice #0
Card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], Device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sub-Devices: 1/1
  Sub-Device #0: subdevice #0
Card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], Device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sub-Devices: 0/1
  Sub-Device #0: subdevice #0
Card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], Device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sub-Devices: 1/1
  Sub-Device #0: subdevice #0
Card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], Device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Sub-Devices: 1/1
  Sub-Device #0: subdevice #0

$ amixer -c0 set Master 5%+
$ amixer -c1 set Master 5%+
```

Both don't work!

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks for all the help!
The answer though came from https://superuser.com/questions/1069981/set-volume-using-php-exec-and-amixer

```
putenv("PULSE_SERVER=/run/user/".getmyuid()."/pulse/native");
```

Comment: Did you check that your apache2 process' environment matches yours?  `amixer` may try to access local settings that are not available to it.

Comment: hm... `echo exec('echo ${HOME}')` outputs the correct path on command line but is empty in browser... so I guess thats the problem? But how to solve this...?

Comment: Could try `putenv()` possibly, http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php

Comment: yes... the question is what variables to set... :P I'll try.

Comment: Try adding the (unintuitive) `putenv('HOME='. getenv('HOME'));` to your script. Most other variables should be working, you might want to compare the phpinfo()-output if something is missing. A suspect could be `ALSA_CONFIG_PATH`.

Comment: You say Apache is running as your user - but does it run in the same session? amixer uses DBUS... I'm blurry on the details, but I assume DBUS is bound to the session, not the user ID. How and where are you starting apache? Perhaps using a more lightweight http server that you can easily run from the command line would be more appropriate for your purpose. You can even write your own :) http://station.clancats.com/writing-a-webserver-in-pure-php/#

Comment: Addendum: Here's a question relating to sharing a DBUS across sessions of the same user: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44317/reuse-d-bus-sessions-across-login-sessions

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps `amixer` isn't addressing the correct [DBUS](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html#whatis) when run from apache. Try setting the `DBUS_ADDRESS` environment variable by invoking `amixer` from a shell script that sets the variable before running `amixer`.

**dbus_amixer.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash
DBUS_ADDRESS=`grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/*/environ 2> /dev/null| sed 's/DBUS/\nDBUS/g' | tail -n 1`
if [ "x$DBUS_ADDRESS" != "x" ]; then
        export $DBUS_ADDRESS
        /usr/bin/amixer set Master 5%+
fi
```

(Code copied from [Running command-line application from PHP as specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913403/running-command-line-application-from-php-as-specific-user))

**amixer.php**

```
<?php
echo exec('dbus_amixer.sh') . " \n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try first running `aplay -L` and you should get output something like this:

```
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=MID
    HDA Intel MID, ALC889 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=MID,DEV=0
    HDA Intel MID, ALC889 Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=MID,DEV=0
    HDA Intel MID, ALC889 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
...
```

Identify which of these is your device, then modify your `amixer ...` command to `amixer -D device ...`, for example `amixer -D surround21:CARD=MID,DEV=0 set Master 5%+`.

This may work.  If not, try `aplay -l` (lowercase), and get the card number.  Then, for example, if the card number is `1`, try `amixer -c 1 set Master 5%+`.

Answer (score 1):

You say that your Apache user runs as your command line user. How far does the similarity extend? I notice that you use short path:

```
echo exec('amixer set Master 5%+')
```

...given that the *user* is the same, you might have **the wrong path** in Apache (PATH settings are not dependent on the user, they're in the user profile, and Apache might load a different profile altogether) - try placing the full path to `amixer` into the exec:

```
echo exec('/usr/local/bin/or/whatever/amixer set Master 5%+') . " \n";
```

Also, for debugging purposes, run `shell_exec` adding `2>&1` stderr redirect to the command line. This might yield some clue as to what exactly is failing.

You can run a more complex command to set up environment:

```
exec(`HOME=whatever FLAGS=somethingelse PATH=/usr/local/... /usr/local/bin/amixer... 2>&1`);
```

To know what the environment variables *are*, you can log as the user, verify that amixer works, dump the environment into a file:

set > set.txt

and check out set.txt for whatever values could apply to amixer. You can run another similar `set` from within Apache, and compare the results (actually I think that the environment is accessible also via `phpinfo()`).

Answer (score 1):

The best and more easy way to get this done is by using xdotool.

```
<?php
shell_exec("DISPLAY=:0 xdotool key XF86AudioMute");
?>

<?php
shell_exec("DISPLAY=:0 xdotool key XF86AudioRaiseVolume");
?>

<?php
shell_exec("DISPLAY=:0 xdotool key XF86AudioLowerVolume");
?>
```

I installed xdotool and configured the rc.xml file on ubuntu openbox with

```
 <!-- Keybinding for Volume management -->
   <keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolume">
     <action name="Execute">
       <command>amixer -D pulse set Master 10%+</command>
     </action>
  </keybind>
   <keybind key="XF86AudioLowerVolume">
     <action name="Execute">
       <command>amixer -D pulse set Master 10%-</command>
     </action>
   </keybind>
   <keybind key="XF86AudioMute">
     <action name="Execute">
       <command>amixer -D pulse set Master 100%-</command>
     </action>
  </keybind>
```

It works like a charm.