# Execute shell script - forever node.js

Tags: node.js, shell-exec, forever

I am running forever scripts, I want control them via a website.

```
if ($_GET['list']) {
    $list = shell_exec("forever list");
    echo ($list);
}
```

but the output is:

> 'No forever processes running'.

When I execute `forever list` on PuTTY it's working. `Su root` didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute your PHP script as the same user that started the processes via forever, otherwise you will get this message saying that no processes are running.

This other question will get you in the right direction; [Running command-line application from PHP as specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913403/running-command-line-application-from-php-as-specific-user)