# Edit sudoers file to only allow specific commands

Tags: php, linux, console, sudoers

I need to run a cPanel script from the command line via PHP's `exec` function (other cPanel options are not viable). The command is roughly:

```
uapi --user=[user] Email suspend_incoming email=[user]%40[domain].[tld]
```

I was getting the following error:

> setuids failed: Attempting to setuid as a normal user with RUID ***

That in turn led me to realize that the user under which PHP runs does *not* have permission to execute that command which lead me to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913403/running-command-line-application-from-php-as-specific-user). *However* just as you're not supposed to CHMOD files blatantly as 777 I don't want to blindly enable all commands for this user when using `sudo` from the command line or PHP's `exec` script.

How do I *only* allow the `uapi` command (also multiple specific commands) to be executed by this user when using `sudo` via an edit to the `sudoers` file?

Comment: Does anything here help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt. Note, if you give the PHP user access to execute this command, it will be available system-wide through any script on the server (assuming it's executed as the same user).

Answer (score -1):

You can give a user access to execute a command as root via an entry to `sudoers` file like so (assuming `www-data` is the PHP process owner user):

```
www-data  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/uapi
```

Obtain the path to the `uapi` file via the command `which uapi`. You should carefully consider the security implications of this action.

[This UNIX stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18877/what-is-the-proper-sudoers-syntax-to-add-a-user) has a nice detailed explanation of the sudo entry syntax.

Comment: *Awesome* except, go figure, cPanel creates some sort of complication. I used `$ which uapi` (thank you *very* much for adding that bit) however it returned "command not found". I do *not* know how the `uapi` is registered to run as it does and am completely void of knowing what to ask let alone do in this scenario?

Comment: Also, do I have to restart Linux for this to take effect?

Comment: The `which` command should return no output if a command is not found. If this happens, then the searched command may not exist in the `PATH`. You may have to search the filesystem for it manually. Also, you shouldn't have to reboot the system for the changes to take effect.