# Running command-line application from PHP which can be run with sudo

Tags: php, bash, shell, nginx, command-line

I am a newbie here, I am having a bash script which can be executed through terminal with sudo permission only. I want to run it from PHP with proper security. I dont know where to start to accomplish this considering security in mind. Should I create a additional user or what Will be the better way to achieve this. I got a reference with [Running command-line application from PHP as specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913403/running-command-line-application-from-php-as-specific-user), but I am using Nginx and the mentioned solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

NGINX is a web server and not the interpreter. It is not very relevant.

In the standard NGINX + PHP-FPM setup, you should have a [separate system user for your website](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-and-php-fpm-what-my-permissions-should-be) anyway. So you don't need to create an extra user just for that command.

Simply ensure that this "website user" is able to `sudo` run your script, without being prompted for their password. This is achieved by `visudo`.

```
example ALL=/path/to/your/script
```

Where `example` is the PHP-FPM pool user, aka, the "website user" and the owner of the website's files.