# How to get the list of pm2 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pm2

I want to build a control panel for all the pm2 in Admin Dashboard and let admin have control to start/stop/restart/delete the running processes. How can i get the list of running pm2 queue in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function

```
$processList=null;
exec('pm2 list',$processList)
```

But you must run PHP with the same user as pm2. If you want to use different user check [Running command-line application from PHP as specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913403/running-command-line-application-from-php-as-specific-user)

Comment: currently my user on pm2 show "laradock" and whereas if i run "whoami" in laravel then it shows "www-data". Can you help how to config for this? @muhammad

Comment: I already linked answer to solving that problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913403/running-command-line-application-from-php-as-specific-user

Comment: Yes thank you but the problem is i'm using laradock and i don't see any sudoers to update the config @muhammad